# Ansible Tower: Send e-mail if the project failed

Tags: ansible

I would like to get a e-mail when the project failed. So I've created a task at the end of the file wich sends me an e-mail. The problem is now that when a task failed also the hole project failed and the e-mail task wouldn't triggered.

Can somebody help me?

(I'm using **Ansible Tower**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins) where you can react on any situation like failed tasks.

[Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/hipchat.py) is an example for a HipChat notification. It's not too hard to modify it to send email messages directly with a local or remote smtp.

**Edit:** Actually there *is* a [mail callback plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/mail.py).

Comment: GitHub links are showing 404 can you please update the links

Answer (score 1):

What if you send the mail from shell depending on the return code of `ansible-playbook` command ?

here's a sample shell script:

```
ANSIBLE_OUTPUT=$(ansible-playbook site.yml -K)

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "playbook failed! OUTPUT: ${ANSIBLE_OUTPUT}" | mail -s "playbook results" your_email@your_email_domain
else
    echo "playbook executed successfully!" | mail -s "playbook results" your_email@your_email_domain
fi
```

Comment: Where should I use this code? I forgot to say that I'm using the ansible tower!

Comment: oh, I didn't think of that. Of course, this won't work on ansible tower.

Answer (score 1):

ansible tower itself provide this feature
you can create a notification template as described in
 https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.0/html/userguide/notifications.html#id1

than from notification option of workflow template, you can select this template on failure or success